# Socket and ObjectInputStream in Java - Android

Tags: java, android, security, encryption, objectinputstream

I have a problem with the Socket and ObjectInputStream using the Cipher class of Java.
I use a client Android, that write an ObjectOutputStream on Socket, and a client Java that read this ObjectInputStream from the same Socket.
This is the code client/server

CLIENT

[CODE]

```
 public static void functionRegistration(String usr, String pwd) throws UnknownHostException, IOException, InvalidKeyException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchProviderException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException{

    Socket socket = new Socket(SERVER_ADDRESS_STRING, PORT_NO);
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

    socket.setSoTimeout(DEFAULT_TIMEOUT);

    if(!socket.isConnected()){
        System.out.println("[!] [Client] Connection problem!");
        socket.close();
        return;
    }

    //Diffie-Hellman
    BigInteger shared_key = DiffieHellmanExchangeClient(socket, br, bw);
    byte[] hash = ObjectHash.getByteHashCode(shared_key, SECURE_HASH_TYPE.SHA384);

    //Extract IV and cipherKey
    byte[] IV = new byte[16];
    byte[] cipherKey = new byte[32];

    int i, limit;

    for(i = 0; i < IV.length; i++)
        IV[i] = hash[i];

    limit = i;

    for(; i < hash.length; i++)
        cipherKey[i - limit] = hash[i];

    //Send username
    bw.write(usr);
    bw.write("\r\n");
    bw.flush();


    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

    //Hash password
    String passwordHash = new String(ObjectHash.getByteHashCode(pwd, SECURE_HASH_TYPE.SHA512));

    //Cipher password
    String encryptedPasswordHash = new String(cipherMessage(passwordHash, cipherKey));

    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
    IvParameterSpec ivparameters = new IvParameterSpec(IV);
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, new SecretKeySpec(cipherKey, "AES"), ivparameters);


    oos.writeObject(new SealedObject(encryptedPasswordHash, cipher));
    oos.flush();


    if(br.readLine().compareTo("ACK") == 0)
        Log.d("ACK", "ACK_RECEIVED");

    else
        Log.d("ACK","Something was wrong");

    br.close();
    bw.close();
    socket.close();
}
```

[\CODE]

SERVER

[CODE]

```
  private void getRegistrationUser() throws IOException, InvalidKeyException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException{
    String username = br.readLine();

    System.out.println("[+] [Server - Thread " + Thread.currentThread().getId() + "] Username received");

    //SHA384 of shared key
    byte[] hash = ObjectHash.getByteHashCode(shared_key, SECURE_HASH_TYPE.SHA384);

    byte[] IV = new byte[16];
    byte[] cipherKey = new byte[32];

    int j, limit;

    for(j = 0; j < IV.length; j++)
        IV[j] = hash[j];

    limit = j;

    for(; j < hash.length; j++)
        cipherKey[j - limit] = hash[j];

    try{

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        IvParameterSpec ivparameters = new IvParameterSpec(IV);
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, new SecretKeySpec(cipherKey, "AES"), ivparameters);

        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(client.getInputStream());
        String encryptedHashPassword = (String)((SealedObject)ois.readObject()).getObject(cipher);

        String decryptedHashPassword = decipherMessage(encryptedHashPassword, cipherKey);

        ois.close();

        sendACK();

    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (BadPaddingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   
}
```

[\CODE]

The two functions in the code cipherMessage and decipherMessage use a Twofish Cipher for encrypt and decrypt data with the respectively key

The problem is that: I note in debug phase that the server is blocking on newObjectInputStream and it is impossibilitate to read the object written by client

How can I solve my problem?

Comment: Does your code work correctly without the encryption / decryption?

Comment: If I remove the operation of Twofish, cipherMessage from client and decipherMessage from server, the code not working. In debug I see that the server is blocked when ties open ObjectInputStream. I don't know why. I also made the flush of ObjectOutputStream in client side

Comment: Where is the Diffie-Hellman in your server code? How have you debugged your application?

Comment: Diffie-Hellman is correct. I tested it. The problem is that I don't able to trasmit crypted information on socket between android and server java, but between a client java and server java works without twofish

Comment: This is probably due to stream handling then; try and use the `ObjectInputStream` on the buffered reader instead; it probably does what it should and read information from the input stream and buffer it, removing it from the stream that the `ObjectInputStream` is trying to read from.

Comment: And so how can I modify the code? I try a lot of possibilities

Comment: You need a different method of reading the bytes. You cannot use `BufferedReader` as you cannot retrieve bytes from a reader directly. One method would be to *encode* the username as bytes, and then send it prepended with the length of the username. Or use a `Reader` until you've read the newline.

Comment: But username from bufferedreader is readed correctly. the problem happen when I try send a crypted information . I remember that if I use this code on a client Java it's work correctly, but with copy and paste on android not working. Why?

Comment: Sorry, Reader also reads ahead.

Comment: And so, what can I do ?

Comment: You need a different method of reading the bytes. You cannot use BufferedReader as you cannot retrieve bytes from a reader directly. One method would be to encode the username as bytes, and then send it prepended with the length of the username.

Comment: Although above scheme will work, adding a String object in the `ObjectOutputStream` as EJP suggests does probably not add *that* much overhead. I think he more or less moved in after reading the comments, but whatever.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use multiple buffered streams on the same socket. They will steal data from each other. Use the object streams for everything.

Comment: And so for you the problem is not on crypt and decrypt information with Twofish cipher. But I have another question: why if I copy and paste this code on a client and server java it's work correctly, exactly with bufferedreader and objectinputstream???

Comment: I guess you can get lucky. It is not specified how much it reads ahead.

Comment: LOL. Then I try to eliminate a bufferedreader andI use only objectinputstream and in the next hour I'll let you know if I solved this problem at least

Comment: @owlstead It's not only not specified, it's indeterminate. It depends not only on the unspecified buffer size but also on the amount of data already present in the socket receive buffer at the moment of the read.

Comment: This solution cannot working because I had another function(DiffieHellmanExchange) that used a BufferedReader and BufferedWriter. If I modify this function with respectively ObjectInputStream and ObjectOutputStream not working.

Comment: Works for me. You modify it how?

Comment: I modify BufferedReader br in ObjectInputStream and BufferedWriter bw in ObjectOutputStream. All method of bufferedreader read and write I translate in readObject and writeObject with cast String.